# On SageMath Cloud, how can I use Python 3 notebooks?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, sage

I'm using the fantastic [SageMath Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/) service to remotely collaborate with a partner. In particular, I'm using IPython notebooks. Unfortunately, the language seems to default to Python 2; I would prefer Python 3.

SSH'ing into my project, I can see that IPython 3 is actually installed. Is there a way to coerce SMC into using Python 3 for notebooks?

I have tried the [instructions mentioned in the FAQ](https://github.com/sagemath/cloud/wiki/FAQ#-question-i-want-to-install-python3-and-use-it-as-my-default), i.e.,

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3 ~/bin/python
ln -s /usr/bin/ipython3 ~/bin/ipython
```

While this works for invoking Python from the SSH commandline, it doesn't seem to affect the kernel used by IPython notebooks created from the web GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you open an IPython Notebook on SageMathCloud you can switch the kernel to a variety of choices, including Python 3. To do that, use the 'Kernel' menu, then 'Change kernel', then 'Python 3'.

Switching to the Python 3 kernel in the IPython Notebook on SageMathCloud is discussed in [this discussion the sage-cloud mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sage-cloud/hHKbvoYN3Qs/discussion).

Is this what your question is about, or are you asking how to make that choice the default when you open a new IPython Notebook on SageMathCloud?

To get the fastest answers to SageMathCloud questions, use [the sage-cloud mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sage-cloud).

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed that kernel option! Seems this is a recent feature? Having it as default would be even more convenient, but this will serve me nicely. Good to know about the mailing list, too.